# Get next data on activated route

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have two components `TodosComponent` and `TodoDetailsComponent`. Clicking on an item in `TodosComponent` takes me to `TodoDetailsComponent` and in the component `ngOnInit` grab the param to fetch the appropriate data. Now, in details component I have next button from which I increase the id and get the result through `router.navigate`. All is working okay. Below is `TodoDetailsComponent`

TodoDetailsComponent.ts

```js
export class TodoDetailsComponent implements OnInit{
  todo;
  id;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private service: Service, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap(params => {
        this.id = +params.get('todoId');
        return this.getTodo(+params.get('todoId'))
      })
    ).subscribe(todo => this.todo = todo);
  }

  getTodo(id) {
    return this.service.getTodo(id);
  }

  next() {
    this.router.navigate(['/todos', this.id+1])
  }
```

What I want to know is what in real life scenario, say as in MongoDB where id's are not in sequence different from this case. To overcome this I tried to map the objects and implicitly add `todoId` in sequence in my service and instead of navigating based on id, navigate based on `todoId`.

Is this okay to do this way or am I missing something in Angular I am not aware of or if anyone have some better or more robust way of doing this.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-activatedroute-next-function?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice.ts) is the complete code for more information about the code if required. Appreciate for any help.

service

```js
getTodos() {
    let todoId = 0;
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}`)
    .pipe(
     map(todos => todos.map(todo => ({...todo, todoId: ++todoId}))
     )
  }
```

Comment: I'm unsure to understand what would be different from those two scenarios?

Comment: @GreatHawkeye Difference is here in this example id's are in sequence and in `next` function I just increase the id by 1 to get the next object in the array, but id's not in sequence in case of mongoDb, so how to get the next object in that case

Comment: As I understand it, your endpoint from mongoDB will give you an array of objects which each object has the values you need in order to display your template. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope @GreatHawkeye order is not the case, what matters is calling next function and getting next object what I am doing in this case as because id's are in sequence and increase by 1 to get the next item here but not in mongoDB. So the question is how to get next item when id's are not in sequence and i cannot increase id by 1 to get next item in case of mongoDB id. Hope now you get me.

Answer (score 0):

If your datas come with this format :

`data = [
    {
      name: 'bob',
      age: 21
    },
    {
      name: 'alice',
      age: 22
    },
    {
      name: 'eric',
      age: 23
    },
  ];`

Maybe you can try something like so :

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  index = 0;

  data = [
    {
      name: 'bob',
      age: 21
    },
    {
      name: 'alice',
      age: 22
    },
    {
      name: 'eric',
      age: 23
    },
  ];

  data$: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = of(this.data);
  }

  previous() {
    if (this.index > 0) {
      this.index--;
    }
  }
  next() {
    if (this.index < this.data.length - 1) {
      this.index++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as item">
  <p>{{ item[index]?.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ item[index]?.age }}</p>
</div>
<button (click)="previous()">Previous</button>
<button (click)="next()">Next</button>
```

You can try it here : https://ng-run.com/edit/HyzjWGNl9xM9Jg2aR90w

Comment: This is what I know Hawkeye, I think you didn't get me or you didn't go through the provided link of the code. Sorry if I am not clear enough for you but if you see the code hope to understand the issue